# How to give path to my Helper.php file in composer.json in Laravel

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, composer-php, helper

I have a function in my helper file But whenever I call that function it looks for it in the controllers but it is present in Helper.php. This was in my Composer.json file before

```
"autoload": {

    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/",
        "Modules\\":"Modules/"
    }
},
```

It gave this error

```
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\moduleStatusCheck()
```

and then I added this to my composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
    "src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php",
            "src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/",
            "Modules\\":"Modules/"
        }
```

And it gives the following error ==>

'''Warning: require(D:\xampp\htdocs\sms\vendor\composer/../../src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php):
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
D:\xampp\htdocs\sms\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 71'''

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 
'D:\xampp\htdocs\sms\vendor\composer/../../src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php' 
(include_path='D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\sms\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 
71
```

I think the path is not right for the Helper.php.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code triggering the problem

Answer (score 0):

I removed app before Helpers/Helper.php

"files": [
"Helpers/Helper.php"

```
    ],
```

And than ran composer dump_autoload and it worked like a charm.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score -1):

Create folder and file:  `app/Helpers/helpers.php`

Edit composer.json:

```
   "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            ...
        },
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
```

Then do `composer dump-autoload`

Enjoy!

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase Isn't that a clear answer to his question?

Comment: That's a good question. If the OP states that it still does not work, it does not look like a good answer to me. Anyways, without any explanation, I would still ask: what makes you think that this is such a clear answer? If that helper file already exists at any path, I don't see any need of recreating it again